# Setting an alias in an ssh session without using bashrc/profile

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, git

How can I set an `alias` on a remote machine over SSH with local ssh config (not editing the remote bashrc/profile files).

Background: I have a remote dev build machine that is shared with a few devs. We only use it for building software and publishing it, but occasionally, we need to make small changes in the code and git commit those. I don't want ssh keys on the remote machine, so we are using SSH agent forwarding so our local SSH keys are available on the remote machine for `git push`. But we still need to set the git `user.name` and `user.email` on the remote machine. Currently, just after logging in, I execute `alias git='git -c "user.name=My Name" -c "user.email=me@mycompany.com"'` so the git commits are attributed to me. Since we share the same account with a few devs, I don't want to set that alias in the remote `~/.bashrc` file. So is there a way to set that command in my local `~/.ssh/config`  for the host so it gets executed in the shell when I login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, from a bunch of different questions I did manage to piece a solution together.
First of all, you can use `RemoteCommand` and `LocalCommand` in your ~/.ssh/config file to execute a local command before logging in, and then instead of just dropping to a shell, execute a different command (shell). I couldn't make it work with only `RemoteCommand` (there is no way it seems to execute a remote command that includes setting an alias), but what you *can* do is provide a different .bashrc file.

So it works like this: copy a local .bashrc file to the remote machine under a different name in /tmp. Login, execute bash and specify the .bashrc file, and at logout, remove it again. Also, when you use `RemoteCommand` in `~/.ssh/config` you need to tell ssh to force a pseudo-tty so you get a normal interactive shell.

This is my relevant section in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host mymachine
    Hostname mymachine.mydomain.com
    ForwardAgent yes
    User someuser
    RequestTTY force
    PermitLocalCommand yes
    LocalCommand scp ~/.sshrc someuser@mymachine.mydomain.com:/tmp/.bashrc_someuser
    RemoteCommand bash --rcfile /tmp/.bashrc_someuser; rm /tmp/.bashrc_someuser
```

The `~/.sshrc` filename is arbitrary. It's just a file anywhere on your local machine. you can even make multiple versions for different remote ssh machines.

This is what my `~/.sshrc` file looks like:

```
source ~/.bashrc
alias git='git -c "user.name=Me" -c "user.email=me@mydomain.com"'
```

This will ensure the `.bashrc` of the remote machine is applied, but then you can add your own customizations afterwards. Now I just ssh there with `ssh mymachine` and the git command works and uses whatever keys I have available in my local machine.